# Create Trigger to reorder a column and modify statement levels

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, compiler-errors

I need to Alter the Product table to have a varchar2(3) reorder column and modify the statement level trigger from the notes to set the product reorder field to “yes” if the quantity on hand is less than twice the product min quantity or if the quantity on hand is less than 10. The value should be “no” otherwise. The trigger is fired after an insert or an update to p_min or p_qoh. Debug by checking the data beforehand, making a change, then checking afterwards.

For this I have

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER 
  TRG_Product_Reorder
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE of P_min, P_qoh ON lab9_Product
BEGIN
  UPDATE lab9_Product SET REORDER = 'yes'
   WHERE P_qoh < P_min*2 or p_qoh < 10;

  UPDATE lab9_Product SET REORDER = 'no'
   WHERE P_qoh >= p_min*2;
END;
/
```

I get the error:

```
SQL statement ignored
"REORDER": invalid identifier
```

Comment: Is "REORDER" the name of the column you're trying to update?  If yes, does it exist in the "lab9_Product" table?

Comment: You can't create a trigger in a table updating it self ! What you can do is change the value of the columns of current updated or inserted row! Think that **IF** it was allowed you end it up in an infinite loop because a new update would call the trigger again!

Comment: What does the statement you executed to add the `REORDER` column to your `LAB9_PRODUCT` table look like?

Comment: hmm ok you are right, I did forget to add REORDER as a column before. 
statement to add REORDER = ALTER TABLE Lab9_Product
ADD REORDER varchar2(3) default 'No'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want a *before* trigger rather than an *after* trigger.  It would be something like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER 
TRG_Product_Reorder
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE of P_min, P_qoh ON 
lab9_Product
BEGIN
    IF :OLD.P_qoh < :OLD.P_min*2 AND :OLD.p_qoh < 10 THEN
       :NEW.REORDER := 'yes';
    ELSE  :NEW.REORDER := 'no';
    END IF;
END;
```